# Undefined reference to TessBaseApi() and pixDestroy

Tags: c++, dll, tesseract, leptonica

I am trying to compile a simple [example](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/APIExample) for using the tesseract api under windows.

Leptonica 1.74.1 was installed through Cmake and msbuild through the steps:

`mkdir build 
cd build
cmake ..
msbuild leptonica.sln`

Tesseract was downloaded from [github](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract) and compiled to build the library (CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH was modified to add the path to LeptonicaConfig.cmake):

`mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
msbuild tesseract.sln`

After these steps, the dlls leptonica-1.74.1d.dll and tesseract400d.dll were created.
The simple [example](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/APIExample) was then compiled through the command mingw32-make with the makefile:

```
CPP64 = x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++
CPP32 = g++ -std=c++11
INC_DIR = -I"C:/OCR/tesseract/tesseract/api" -I"C:/OCR/leptonica-1.74.1/src" \
          -I"C:/OCR/tesseract/tesseract/ccutil" -I"C:/OCR/tesseract/tesseract/ccstruct" \
          -I "C:/OCR/tesseract/tesseract/ccmain" -I"C:/OCR/leptonica-1.74.1/build/src"
LINK_DIR = -L"C:/OCR/tesseract/tesseract/build/bin/Debug" -L"C:/OCR/leptonica-1.74.1/build/bin/Debug"
LINK_LIB = -lleptonica-1.74.1d -ltesseract400d
OBJECTS = main.o 
EXECUTABLES = main.exe

all: $(EXECUTABLES)

main.exe: main.o
    $(CPP32) -o $@ $< $(LINK_DIR) $(LINK_LIB)   

main.o: 
    $(CPP32) $(INC_DIR) -c main.cpp

clean:
    rm $(EXECUTABLES) $(OBJECTS)
```

But the compilation fails due to undefined references:

`` main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x29): undefined reference to `tesseract::TessBaseAPI::Te
ssBaseAPI()'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x91): undefined reference to `pixRead'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xa4): undefined reference to `tesseract::TessBaseAPI::Se
tImage(Pix*)'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xb1): undefined reference to `tesseract::TessBaseAPI::Ge
tUTF8Text()'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xd1): undefined reference to `tesseract::TessBaseAPI::En
d()'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xed): undefined reference to `pixDestroy' ``

I checked issue [#377](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/377) and [#582](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/582) but they did not help. It seems like both leptonica and tesseract dll are not linked properly (pixDestroy function is from leptonica while tho others are from tesseract)